# Show that if $A$ is symmetric, then $R$ is symmetric, and hence a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P$ be an orthogonal matrix, $R$ be an upper triangular matrix, and $A=PRP^{-1}$. Show that if $A$ is symmetric, then $R$ is symmetric, and hence a diagonal matrix.

My approach:

Suppose $A=PRP^{-1}$. Since $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, it has orthogonal columns, and these columns are linearly independent, so $P$ is invertible and we can express $R$ as $R=P^{-1}AP$.

Since $P$ is orthogonal, $P^{-1}=P^T$ and since $A$ is symmetric $A=A^T$, transposing $R$ we show that $R$ is symmetric:

$$R^T=(P^{-1}AP)^T=P^TA^T(P^{-1})^T=P^TA^T(P^T)^T=P^{-1}AP=R$$

From here how do I show that $R$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Upper triangular matrix that is symmetric is diagonal. Since it's lower diagonal part is zero and also is equal to the upper diagonal part, due to the symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R$ is an upper matrix then it has the form
$$
R = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{11} } & {a_{12} } &  \cdots  & {a_{1n} }  \\
   0 & {a_{22} } &  \cdots  & {a_{2n} }  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & {a_{nn} }  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
and so that $R^T$ has the form $$
R^T  = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{11} } & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \\
   {a_{12} } & {a_{22} } &  \cdots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   {a_{1n} } & {a_{2n} } &  \cdots  & {a_{nn} }  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
Now, since $R$ is symmetric $R=R^T$ then by comparing the corresponding terms in $R$ and $R^T$ then we find that 
$$ R = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{11} } & {a_{12} } &  \cdots  & {a_{1n} }  \\
   0 & {a_{22} } &  \cdots  & {a_{2n} }  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & {a_{nn} }  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{11} } & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \\
   {a_{12} } & {a_{22} } &  \cdots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   {a_{1n} } & {a_{2n} } &  \cdots  & {a_{nn} }  \\
\end{array}} \right) = R^T 
$$
so that $$
\begin{array}{l}
 a_{12}  = 0,a_{13}  = 0, \ldots ,a_{1n}  = 0 \\ 
 a_{21}  = 0,a_{23}  = 0, \ldots ,a_{2n}  = 0 \\ 
  \vdots  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$ which means that $
R = \left( {a_{ii} } \right)$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is so far correct. For the remaining part you just need to consider that $R$ is symmetric *and* assumed to be an upper diagonal matrix.